# Undefine a function-like macro in C?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, glibc

I am trying to do some hacks over the glibc, and I wanted to know whether it's possible to redefine function-like macros ?

For example, `<tgmath.h>` has the following macro:

```
#define expm1(Val) __TGMATH_UNARY_REAL_ONLY (Val, expm1)
```

How to redefine `expm1` as :

```
#define expm1(Val) __TGMATH_UNARY_REAL_IMAG (Val, expm1, cexpm1)
```

I suppose that I have to cancel the previous definition but I do not know exactly how to do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exactly. Just undefine it first.

```
#ifdef expm1
#undef expm1
#endif

#define expm1(Val) __TGMATH_UNARY_REAL_IMAG (Val, expm1, cexpm1)
```

Comment: To improve the answer: just undefine it if it was previously defined.

Comment: @Vincent, what should that be good for? The result would be exactly the same, namely that `expm1` is undefined thereafter.

Comment: @Vincent Added that for you.