# How to undefine system function-like macros?

Tags: macos, clang, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to build a code which defines a method `howmany()`.

In OSX there is a function-like macro with the same name in `/usr/include/sys/types.h`

```
#define howmany(x, y)   __DARWIN_howmany(x, y)
```

Following [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958638/undefine-a-function-like-macro-in-c), I've tried including `#undef` in the header file as

```
#ifdef howmany
#undef howmany /*undefining '/usr/include/sys/types.h' */
#endif
```

But the function-like macro remains active.

> /usr/include/sys/types.h:184:9: note: macro 'howmany' defined here #define howmany(x, y)   __DARWIN_howmany(x, y)  /* # y's == x bits? */

How should I deactivate this function-like macro?

Comment: I tried it just now, and a simple `#undef howmany` after `#include <sys/types.h>` works fine for me.

Comment: This is incredibly fragile. Yes, you can probably get it to work, but very small changes to how things are imported will cause it to fail again (or worse, just call the wrong code). You need to make sure that `#undef` is included in every file that might include `types.h` and that it's undefined after it's defined. This is many ways it can break. Rename your function. The name is taken.

Comment: @Rob Napier please make than an answer. It is a good one and I want to vote it up. I also want this to be an answered question, so that it gets off my "answers:0" list. And Q/A pairs are so much nicer than Q/comment pairs. And you are so right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is incredibly fragile. Yes, you can probably get it to work, but very small changes to how things are imported will cause it to fail again (or worse, just call the wrong code). You need to make sure that `#undef` is included in every file that might include `types.h` and that it's undefined after it's defined. This is many ways it can break. Rename your function. The name is taken.

Comment: I accept the answer, but in the end I decided to change name to all the functions in the code.